# Every closed (not-necessarily symmetric) monoidal category is canonically self-enriched, right?

Tags: category-theory

[Here](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=icriC6ay5xcC&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=every+closed+monoidal+category+is+canonically+self-enriched&source=bl&ots=89qLVYVnKl&sig=DYLEbpCOfqU83Ms7guYxik0t2ZY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IuzpU8LUKNW58gXK4ID4Bg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=every%20closed%20monoidal%20category%20is%20canonically%20self-enriched&f=false) it is stated that:

> A closed symmetric monoidal category is canonically self-enriched.

This makes sense, but I don't see why it has to be symmetric. Every closed (not-necessarily symmetric) monoidal category is canonically self-enriched, right? If not, what goes wrong?

Comment: no need for symmetry at all.

Comment: It is unusual to consider categories enriched in something other than a symmetric monoidal category in the first place – partly because a lot of the theory becomes awkward (e.g. opposite categories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ittay Weiss:

> no need for symmetry at all.

Zhen Lin:

> It is unusual to consider categories enriched in something other than a symmetric monoidal category in the first place – partly because a lot of the theory becomes awkward (e.g. opposite categories).

Comment: I will accept this answer in 2 days if nothing else comes along in the meantime.